# I cant change the font size or family in my bootstrap 4 navbar

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar, font-size, font-family

Hi I have tried multiple different solutions from this site and others but I cant figure out what is wrong with my code. I am very new to coding so excuse me if it's obvious.

I cant change my font-family or size etc of the nav links from the css.

Here is the code.

```html
 </head>
  <body>
    <section class="header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"
            ><img
              src="images/Twisted-white-flat-7-7's.png"
              alt="the-twisted-spirit-7-7s"
              height="100px"
          /></a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
            aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" ;
                  >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
                >
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" ;>Link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input
                class="form-control mr-sm-2"
                type="search"
                placeholder="Search"
              />
              <button
                class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0"
                type="submit"
              >
                Search
              </button>
            </form> -->
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
```

If you need anything else please ask. Thank you.

Comment: It could be an issue with precedence as @CanUver suggests. Also selectors by element type are outranked by selectors by class which are in turn outranked by selectors by id. The !important keyword should override everything but it's not a great practice to use it when you don't have to in my opinion -  it may limit your options in future. Perhaps you'll need a media query to change font-size and then you'll be forced to reuse the keyword. It would help to see the css you are using to try to change the font.  Hope this helps,  Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your help guys. When asdf prompted me to go into developer tools I found out the correct syntax and identifiers to get the look I wanted through seeing an all ready identifying color of the link I wanted to change. Before that I was using all types of crazy combinations.

The code I needed was

```css
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  font-family: "Six Caps";
  font-size: xx-large;
}
```

Thanks again for all your help guys, much appreciated.

p.s someone asked what framework I was using and it is bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1):

How are you loading the bootstrap css? And what (if any) framework are you using?

If you want to override Bootstrap's navbar styling, you can make your own css file and make your edits in there.

Here's a very simple example (I'm using the Django framework, so that's why you'll see the `{% %}`):

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'example/style.css' %}">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Navbar</span>
</nav>
<p>the test page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```css
.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Here's what the navbar looks like before overriding the `navbar-brand` class:

[image: before]

and after making my own style.css file and overriding Bootstrap's:

[image: after]

If you want to create your own class, you can make an entirely new one in your style.css file:

```css
.custom-navbar-blue {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: blue;
}
```

And be sure to edit the line in your html:

```html
  <span class="custom-navbar-blue">Navbar</span>
```

[image: blue_navbar]

If you're ever not sure why something doesn't look how you expect, you can use the "developer tools" > "inspect" option in your browser. If you're using firefox, the shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+C; if you're using chrome, the shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+I. You'll be able to see what CSS is being loaded and what is getting overridden. If your CSS isn't getting loaded for some reason, you'll see that in the "Network" tab.

Comment: Thanks for that, the dev tools really helped identify that I was using the wrong identifiers to target it with my css, I had checked before but it somehow clicked from you sending me there. The identifier I needed to use was .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  font-family: "Six Caps";
  font-size: xx-large;
}

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use `!important` ?

because when you classify with bootstrap, it acts as an inline css. You know right ?

```css
font-family : 'example family' !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Sass variables to change the font size, if you're using Sass of course

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_variables.scss